# How to get specific rows in a txt file in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, text

Here is my problem, I am trying to make a script that create a new table in a database for each new txt file I get. This part is ok but then I want to get some specific rows or words in the txt file to update the table.

Here is my code :

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost"; 
    $username = "root";        
    $password = "";            
    $dbname = "exctraction";         

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 

    if ($conn->connect_error)
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);    
    } 



    foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) 
    { 

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$filename` (
               `id` int(100) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,         
               `device` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
               `label` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
                           `configured` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
               PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
            )  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;"; 


        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
        {
            echo "<b>La table ".$filename."&nbsp;"." a &eacute;t&eacute; cr&eacute;&eacute;e avec succ&egrave;s.</b> </br>"; 
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "<u>Erreur lors de la cr&eacute;ation de la table :</u> </br>" . $conn->error; 
        }

                $file  = fopen( $filename, "r" );
                $content = "";

                for( $i = 0 ; $i < 158 ; $i++)  
                {

                    $content .= fgets($file, 200);
                    if($i==65)
                    {
                        $content_array = file($filename);
                        print_r ($content."</br>");
                    }

                }
                fclose($file);
        }
        ?>
```

I want to display the lines I need and then make an UPDATE TABLE with these lines.

The lines I want to get are from 57 to 65 in the txt file, but I am not able to get these only lines.

Comment: Remove "." from `$content .= fgets($file, 200);`

Comment: I tried and nothing displays..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$File = "file.txt";   // I assume your file has 57th and 65th line
$fhandle = fopen($File, 'r'); 
while(!feof($fhandle)) // until end of file
{
    $data[] = fgets($fhandle);  // place each line to array
    //Do whatever you want with the data in here
    //This feeds the file into an array line by line
}
fclose($fhandle);
echo "<pre>"; // makes output easier to read
print_r($data[56].$data[64]); // outputs 57th and 65th line

?>
```

Comment: To display the lines 58 to 65 what do I write?

Comment: My bad, was in a hurry. Added a bit of explanation.

Comment: This doesn't display all the lines from 58 to 65, just the 58 and 59th and they are not complete.

Comment: Then you need a for loop to go through it

for($i=58;$i<=65;$i++){
    echo $data[$i];
}